# Issue with sqlite join

Tags: sqlite

Here is my db schema:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    transaction_id integer primary key autoincrement,
    total_price integer not null
);
CREATE TABLE order_items (
    transaction_id integer REFERENCES orders(transaction_id),
    SKU integer not null,
    product_name text not null,
    unit_price integer not null,
    quantity integer not null
);
```

What I am trying to do is take the last row from the orders table and match that transaction_id to all items that contain the same transaction_id in the order_items table

I tried this sqlite query to no avail:

```
sqlite> SELECT orders.transaction_id, orders.total_price
   ...> FROM orders
   ...> ORDER BY transaction_id DESC LIMIT 1
   ...> WHERE orders.transaction_id = order_items.transaction_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ORDER BY must come after the WHERE.
However, the LIMIT 1 will return only one record.

You cannot access columns from `order_items` without mentioning it in the FROM clause.

You should filter the transaction with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
JOIN order_items USING (transaction_id)
WHERE orders.transaction_id = (SELECT MAX(transaction_id)
                               FROM orders)
```